# jwplayer error loading could not load player configration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jwplayer

When we share video on facebook using my server video url. I already use all og tags which are required for sharing video on facebook. Video play on my server but when we share video url on facebook and click on video it gives me error loading could not load player configration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iPhone To Server Live bradcasting</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/videofb/player.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Live stream testing by navjot singh" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Live stream description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZTUtP6pBZU8/maxresdefault.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf?file=https%3A%2F%2Fbelive.mobi%2Fmultitvfinal%2Fvideofb%2Fkinley.mp4" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/jwplayer/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="vxdWEF/4dRcCz9DVqhR3L6GDhNCprcASMR4YpA==";</script>

</head>
<body>
Live
<div id="player">
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("player").setup({primary:"flash",playlist:[{sources:[{file:"https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/videofb/kinley.mp4"},],width:"480",height:"320",rtmp:{bufferlength:5},primary:"flash",accelerated:"true",border:"0",autoBuffering:"true",startparam:"ec_seek",androidhls:"true",stretching:"fill",}]});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer("player").setup({primary:"flash",file:"https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/videofb/kinley.mp4",height:360,width:640});</script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "https://belive.mobi/multitvfinal/videofb/kinley.mp4",
        image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZTUtP6pBZU8/maxresdefault.jpg",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</div>
<div><br/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Contact JW Player support to get a copy of JW5, which works in FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of JW Player can't be embedded on Facebook. To do that, you'll need a special version, available only directly from JW Player, and only available to those with a "Premium" license or better (not even a "Pro" license will suffice).

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1826071-embedding-jw-player-onto-facebook